# Insert objects inside a Grid from c#

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I have a Grid with some rows and columns in the xaml code. in the c # code I have a list, and I would like every object contained within it to be positioned in a specific point of the Grid. For example: object 1: column 1 row 1, object 2: column 2 row 1 etc. etc. How could I do?

```
<Grid Margin="15">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

List with some objects inside

```
ObservableCollection<HumorDiary> listDiario = new ObservableCollection<HumorDiary>();
```

The items in the list may vary, they do not have a predetermined number.
For each element in the list I would like to create a button in the Grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Grid` has a `Children` collection

```
myGrid.Children.Add(myElement, col, row);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ItemsControl`, which has four parts:

- You bind your collection to the `ItemsSource` property.
- You define your item template, which determines how your model item (`HumorDiary`) is displayed on screen.
- You define your panel template, which defines how your items are grouped together. In this case, this would be the `Grid` you defined above.
- To position these things in your grid, you style your item template and bind the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties to properties that define where they should be added.

Comment: this is a Xamarin project.  ItemsControl is not available

Comment: There are plenty of `ItemsControl` implementations for Xamarin, pick one and go with it!